# libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)

Tags: fedora, mesa, ldconfig

I'm trying to run an app on Fedora 33, but when I run the executable, I get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  52
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

I tried following the thread here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/hhytvl/libgl_error_mesaloader_failed_to_open_iris/ but haven't gotten anything to work

Note that the driver `iris_dri.so` is present in both `/usr/lib/dri` and `/usr/lib64/dri`

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same warning (but the iris part only) on my Gentoo Linux system.  In my case, the solution was to reinstall the **mesa** package with support for iris video cards.  Apparently, the "Intel iRISx graphics" sticker on my laptop would have suggested that, had I been sufficiently knowledgeable to recognise it.

I don't know what the equivalent is for fedora systems, but something along the same lines (an iris option for the mesa package?; a separate iris package?) should fix your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, and its solution, are explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71010344/6079195. Basically you need to force loading the libstdc++.so.6 in your system with precedence over another version.

To locate this file in your filesystem:

```
find / -name libstdc++.so.6 2>/dev/null
```

Then add the export LD_PRELOAD to the .bashrc file, e.g.:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, you missed the crux of the issue:
`libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

`libnsl.so.1` isn't available on the system. It needs to be installed. It may be present in package `libnsl`. A generic answer is to provide a way to search which package contains a file, for example, using `dnf provides libnsl.so.1` (See point 13 at [25 Useful DNF Command Examples For Package Management In Linux @ RootUsers](https://www.rootusers.com/25-useful-dnf-command-examples-for-package-management-in-linux/)).